# Katalon Studio: Running Test-Case on Mobile android emulator error message appears: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome ‘113.0.5672’

Tags: android, mobile, selenium-chromedriver, katalon-studio

I am using windows 10, katalon studio 9.3.0 Build 212.
Running Android Mobile Test-Case the error message **“No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome ‘113.0.5672’.”** appears.

I added the newly downloaded ChromeDriver to the

```
"C:\Users<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win"
```

folder, but the error message is still the same.

**Does anyone have an idea what I’m doing wrong?**

```
> <<<< Error log >>>
*=============== ROOT CAUSE =====================
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '113.0.5672'. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers download as a possible workaround.

For trouble shooting, please visit: https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/troubleshooting.html
================================================

02-13-2024 06:17:51 PM Test Cases/Verify Login CURA System Successfully - Mobile Browsers

Elapsed time: 1m - 3,899s
```

Test Cases/Verify Login CURA System Successfully - Mobile Browsers FAILED.

```
Reason:
com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to open browser with url: 'https://katalon-demo-cura.herokuapp.com/'
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.stepFailed(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:64)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:26)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.openBrowser(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:81)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.execute(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:67)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:74)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords.openBrowser(WebUiBuiltInKeywords.groovy:64)
    at Verify Login CURA System Successfully - Mobile Browsers.run(Verify Login CURA System Successfully - Mobile Browsers:11)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:448)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:439)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:418)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:410)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:285)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:137)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:128)
    at TempTestCase1707844660113.run(TempTestCase1707844660113.groovy:25)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '113.0.5672'. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers download as a possible workaround.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'DE-L086418', ip: '192.168.178.82', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: driver.version: SwipeableAndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '113.0.5672'. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers download as a possible workaround.
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\RatschmeierR\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:1118:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\RatschmeierR\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:491:57)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'DE-L086418', ip: '192.168.178.82', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: driver.version: SwipeableAndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.appium.driver.SwipeableAndroidDriver.execute(SwipeableAndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:85)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.appium.driver.SwipeableAndroidDriver.<init>(SwipeableAndroidDriver.java:23)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.appium.driver.AppiumDriverManager.createMobileDriver(AppiumDriverManager.java:560)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.appium.driver.AppiumDriverManager.createMobileDriver(AppiumDriverManager.java:542)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.WebMobileDriverFactory.createMobileDriver(WebMobileDriverFactory.java:177)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory.startNewBrowser(DriverFactory.java:386)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory.openWebDriver(DriverFactory.java:266)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword$_openBrowser_closure1.doCall(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:74)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword$_openBrowser_closure1.call(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:20)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.openBrowser(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:81)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.execute(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:67)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:74)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords.openBrowser(WebUiBuiltInKeywords.groovy:64)
    at Script1674800693527.run(Script1674800693527.groovy:11)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '113.0.5672'. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers download as a possible workaround.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'DE-L086418', ip: '192.168.178.82', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: driver.version: SwipeableAndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '113.0.5672'. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers download as a possible workaround.
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\RatschmeierR\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:1118:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\RatschmeierR\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:491:57)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.appium.driver.SwipeableAndroidDriver.execute(SwipeableAndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:85)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.appium.driver.SwipeableAndroidDriver.<init>(SwipeableAndroidDriver.java:23)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.appium.driver.AppiumDriverManager.createMobileDriver(AppiumDriverManager.java:560)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.appium.driver.AppiumDriverManager.createMobileDriver(AppiumDriverManager.java:542)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.WebMobileDriverFactory.createMobileDriver(WebMobileDriverFactory.java:177)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory.startNewBrowser(DriverFactory.java:386)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory.openWebDriver(DriverFactory.java:266)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword$_openBrowser_closure1.doCall(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:74)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword$_openBrowser_closure1.call(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:20)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.openBrowser(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:81)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.execute(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:67)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:74)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords.openBrowser(WebUiBuiltInKeywords.groovy:64)
    at Verify Login CURA System Successfully - Mobile Browsers.run(Verify Login CURA System Successfully - Mobile Browsers:11)
    ... 13 more*
```